# Craft CMS login 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, login, htaccess, craft3

I transferred a website using Craft CMS and now when I want login to admin the console return me

```
jquery-2.2.1.min.js?d=1493126871:4 POST http://website.com/index.php/admin/actions/users/login 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I put app to debug mode and I have very more error like to

```
[14:44:38.309][trace][system.CModule] Loading "cache" application component in /home/domains/website.ca/public_html/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (593)
```

I try put `RewriteBase /` and ma .htaccess my site is multilang so i put this and the .htaccess of each file /en and /fr

The website is at a hosting company and a not access to ssh . The PHP version is 7 and a have activate all module

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but I often find the 500 Internal errors are me having the config/db.php or config/general.php files with incorrect information.

Comment: Is it a Craft styled 500 (like a grey box centered in the middle of the screen) or an "ugly" Apache one? It sounds like you messed up your .htaccess file.  If you mess up that file, Apache will also throw a 500.

Answer (score 2):

remove /craft/storage/runtime and remove all craft_session and database

Comment: This has been downvoted, but removing the runtime folder worked a treat for me.